# How to exclude nod_module style css in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

How to exclude below node_module Bootstrap style file.

```
node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_reboot.scss
```

Because of this file my custom styles are overriding.

I tried removing below properties in angular.json file, but still bootstrap styles are applying.

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved by updating font-family value in **/src/styles/_base.scss**

body {
  font-family: $primary-font;
}

**to**

```
body {
  font-family: $font-family-base;
}
```